# how to use insoshi in rails 3 for making a social networking site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, social-networking, platform

I am trying to install Insoshi but don't know how to install it. I've tried the read-me file many times but get stuck in the Install script section. Whenever I use this line

```
$ cp config/database.example config/database.yml
```

on my terminal, it returns as

```
cp: cannot stat `config/database.example': No such file or directory.
```

When I use script/install it says:

```
'script' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I am using Windows 7 and Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.3. Hoping for help.